# Fabric.js background of IText object misses boundingbox

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, bounding-box

I have some problems when creating `IText` objects in Fabric.js. The problem is that the background of the `IText` does not match its bounding box. Basically what I do is this, see JSFiddle below for demo.

```
    //Regular text, works
    text1 = new fabric.Text('Regular text', {
        fill: 'red',
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0, 0.65)'
    });

    //IText misses
    text2 = new fabric.IText('Interactive text \nbackground misses \nboundingbox', {
        fill: 'blue',
        left: 100,
        top: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0, 0.65)'
    });

    canvas.add(text1);
    canvas.add(text2);
    text1.setCoords();
    text2.setCoords();
    canvas.calcOffset();
    canvas.renderAll();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qL2y/18/)

Comment: Hm, might be a bug. It works correctly with "textBackgroundColor" but not with "backgroundColor". Please file an issue on github!

Comment: I'm confused. iText is a Trademark owned by 1T3XT. It refers to a PDF library. Are you talking about that iText? Or is somebody using the trademarked name in another context?

Comment: Itext as Interactive text element from FabricJS lib. Not the PDF lib.